# How to work with sforce.opencti library in Lightning Web Components

Tags: lightning-web-components, opencti

Are LWC ready to be used for implementing opencti adapter? I didn't find any information on that. In aura it was simple, however in LWC I can't find a way to make it work.

Comment: can you show sample in aura?

Comment: If you're working in the console, the Lightning Console isn't fully compatible with LWC yet.

Comment: @salesforce-sas aura example can be found in the official demo https://github.com/developerforce/open-cti-demo-adapter. You just include it in the VFP and then use it in aura.

Comment: Does anyone know when we can expect all the console APIs to be made available to aura and/or LWC? The capabilities for the classic are great, and it would be very helpful if there's a way to include it in LWC.